# Django: how to pass parameters to forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Django form that is rendered with bootstrap3.  I want to be able to pass parameters into my form to make it more generic. My forms looks like:

```
class SpacecraftID(forms.Form):
  def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    choices = kwargs.pop('choices')
    #self.choices = kwargs.pop('choices') produces same error
    super(SpacecraftID,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

  scID = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=choices)
```

And my view looks like:

```
def schedule_search(request):
 choices = (
    ('1','SAT1'),
    ('2','SAT2'),
    ('3','SAT3'),
    )

 if request.method == 'POST':
    form_ID = SpacecraftID(request.POST,choices=choices)
    if form.is_valid():
        scID = form_ID.cleaned_data['scID']

 else:
    form_ID = SpacecraftID(choices=choices)

 return render(request, 'InterfaceApp/schedule_search.html', {'form3': form_ID})
```

When I run this code I get the error:

NameError at /InterfaceApp/schedule_search/,
name 'choices' is not defined

Comment: Please add a complete traceback of error

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the `choices` variable is not available when you define your form fields, that is when Python parse the `forms.py` file, it is only available when the form is instantiated, inside `__init__`. You then need to update the field inside `__init__`.

```
class SpacecraftID(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        choices = kwargs.pop('choices')

        super(SpacecraftID,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

        # Set choices from argument.
        self.fields['scId'].choices = choices

    # Set choices to an empty list as it is a required argument.
    scID = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=[])
```

Comment: changing `choices = kwargs.pop('choices')` to `self.choices = kwargs.pop('choices')` produces the same error

Comment: @klwahl You cannot use `choices` in the `scID` field definition. I had not seen you where using it here. I'll try to edit my answer to make it work.