# Pass parameter to django form

Tags: django, django-forms

I need to dynamically create a choice field in Django Form (not ModelForm) using the logged user as a parameter.

The view:

```
def cadastro(request):
    medico = request.user.medico
    usuario=request.user
    clinicas = medicos.clinicas.all()
    escolhas = tuple([(c.id, c.nome.clinica) for c in clinicas])
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
           formulario = NovoProcesso(escolhas, request.POST)

        if formulario.is_valid(): 
        formulario.save(usuario)
        
else:
    formulario = NovoProcesso(escolhas)

contexto = {'formulario': formulario, 'clinicas': clinicas}  

return render(request, 'processos/cadastro.html', contexto)
```

Form class:

```
class NovoProcesso(forms.Form):
 def __init__(self, escolhas, *args, **kwargs):
     super(NovoProcesso, self).__init__(escolhas, *args, **kwargs) -------> the source of the problem is here.

     self.fields['clinicas'].choices = escolhas


 clinicas = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=[])
 # there are other fields here, but I ommited for the sake of clarity

  def(save):
  #custom save method....
```

I incorrectly passed arguments to the init method as described here:
[object has no attribute 'get'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667845/object-has-no-attribute-get)

I'm having trouble to understand the line:
self.fields['clinicas'].choices = escolhas

Not sure if I should write self.fields['clinicas].choices or . widget.... not sure how to write de form field inside the class. Tried several variations.

I'm getting the following error:

> Internal Server Error: /processos/cadastro/ Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File
> "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py",
> line 158, in **getitem**
> field = self.fields[name] KeyError: 'errors'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 828, in _resolve_lookup
> current = current[bit]   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py",
> line 160, in **getitem**
> raise KeyError( KeyError: "Key 'errors' not found in 'NovoProcesso'. Choices are: altura, anamnese, cid, clinicas,
> cpf_paciente, data_1, diagnostico, incapaz, med1, med1_posologia_mes1,
> nome_mae, nome_paciente, nome_responsavel, peso, qtd_med1_mes1,
> qtd_med1_mes2, qtd_med1_mes3, tratamentos_previos, tratou."
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
> line 34, in inner
> response = get_response(request)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
> line 115, in _get_response
> response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
> line 113, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py",
> line 21, in _wrapped_view
> return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/lucas/dev/autocusto/processos/views.py", line 101, in cadastro
> return render(request, 'processos/cadastro.html', contexto)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py",
> line 19, in render
> content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)   File
> "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py",
> line 62, in render_to_string
> return template.render(context, request)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py",
> line 61, in render
> return self.template.render(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 171, in render
> return self._render(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 163, in _render
> return self.nodelist.render(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 936, in render
> bit = node.render_annotated(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 903, in render_annotated
> return self.render(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py",
> line 150, in render
> return compiled_parent._render(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 163, in _render
> return self.nodelist.render(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 936, in render
> bit = node.render_annotated(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 903, in render_annotated
> return self.render(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py",
> line 62, in render
> result = block.nodelist.render(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 936, in render
> bit = node.render_annotated(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 903, in render_annotated
> return self.render(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 986, in render
> output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 670, in resolve
> obj = self.var.resolve(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 795, in resolve
> value = self._resolve_lookup(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 836, in _resolve_lookup
> current = getattr(current, bit)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py",
> line 175, in errors
> self.full_clean()   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py",
> line 376, in full_clean
> self._clean_fields()   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py",
> line 388, in _clean_fields
> value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))   File
> "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py",
> line 258, in value_from_datadict
> return data.get(name) AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get' [20/Dec/2019 13:09:03] "GET /processos/cadastro/
> HTTP/1.1" 500 215106 /home/lucas/dev/autocusto/processos/views.py
> changed, reloading. Watching for file changes with StatReloader
> Performing system checks...
>
> System check identified no issues (0 silenced). December 20, 2019 -
> 13:11:10 Django version 3.0, using settings 'autocusto.settings'
> Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Quit the server
> with CONTROL-C. /home/lucas/dev/autocusto/processos/forms.py changed,
> reloading. Watching for file changes with StatReloader Performing
> system checks...
>
> System check identified no issues (0 silenced). December 20, 2019 -
> 13:11:24 Django version 3.0, using settings 'autocusto.settings'
> Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Quit the server
> with CONTROL-C. [(1, 'SHAM'), (2, '65'), (3, '65asdfasdf'), (4,
> 'Clínica 1'), (5, 'Clínica 2'), (6, 'Clínica 3')] Internal Server
> Error: /processos/cadastro/ Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py",
> line 158, in **getitem**
> field = self.fields[name] KeyError: 'errors'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 828, in _resolve_lookup
> current = current[bit]   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py",
> line 160, in **getitem**
> raise KeyError( KeyError: "Key 'errors' not found in 'NovoProcesso'. Choices are: altura, anamnese, cid, clinicas,
> cpf_paciente, data_1, diagnostico, incapaz, med1, med1_posologia_mes1,
> nome_mae, nome_paciente, nome_responsavel, peso, qtd_med1_mes1,
> qtd_med1_mes2, qtd_med1_mes3, tratamentos_previos, tratou."
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
> line 34, in inner
> response = get_response(request)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
> line 115, in _get_response
> response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
> line 113, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py",
> line 21, in _wrapped_view
> return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/lucas/dev/autocusto/processos/views.py", line 101, in cadastro
> return render(request, 'processos/cadastro.html', contexto)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py",
> line 19, in render
> content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)   File
> "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py",
> line 62, in render_to_string
> return template.render(context, request)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py",
> line 61, in render
> return self.template.render(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 171, in render
> return self._render(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 163, in _render
> return self.nodelist.render(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 936, in render
> bit = node.render_annotated(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 903, in render_annotated
> return self.render(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py",
> line 150, in render
> return compiled_parent._render(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 163, in _render
> return self.nodelist.render(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 936, in render
> bit = node.render_annotated(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 903, in render_annotated
> return self.render(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py",
> line 62, in render
> result = block.nodelist.render(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 936, in render
> bit = node.render_annotated(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 903, in render_annotated
> return self.render(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 986, in render
> output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 670, in resolve
> obj = self.var.resolve(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 795, in resolve
> value = self._resolve_lookup(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 836, in _resolve_lookup
> current = getattr(current, bit)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py",
> line 175, in errors
> self.full_clean()   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py",
> line 376, in full_clean
> self._clean_fields()   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py",
> line 388, in _clean_fields
> value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))   File
> "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py",
> line 258, in value_from_datadict
> return data.get(name) AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get' [20/Dec/2019 13:11:28] "GET /processos/cadastro/
> HTTP/1.1" 500 215100 /home/lucas/dev/autocusto/processos/forms.py
> changed, reloading. Watching for file changes with StatReloader
> Performing system checks...
>
> System check identified no issues (0 silenced). December 20, 2019 -
> 13:13:15 Django version 3.0, using settings 'autocusto.settings'
> Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Quit the server
> with CONTROL-C. /home/lucas/dev/autocusto/processos/views.py changed,
> reloading. Watching for file changes with StatReloader Performing
> system checks...
>
> System check identified no issues (0 silenced). December 20, 2019 -
> 13:25:04 Django version 3.0, using settings 'autocusto.settings'
> Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Quit the server
> with CONTROL-C. [20/Dec/2019 13:30:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3680 Not
> Found: /favicon.ico ((1, 'SHAM'), (2, '65'), (3, '65asdfasdf'), (4,
> 'Clínica 1'), (5, 'Clínica 2'), (6, 'Clínica 3')) Internal Server
> Error: /processos/cadastro/ Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py",
> line 158, in **getitem**
> field = self.fields[name] KeyError: 'errors'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 828, in _resolve_lookup
> current = current[bit]   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py",
> line 160, in **getitem**
> raise KeyError( KeyError: "Key 'errors' not found in 'NovoProcesso'. Choices are: altura, anamnese, cid, clinicas,
> cpf_paciente, data_1, diagnostico, incapaz, med1, med1_posologia_mes1,
> nome_mae, nome_paciente, nome_responsavel, peso, qtd_med1_mes1,
> qtd_med1_mes2, qtd_med1_mes3, tratamentos_previos, tratou."
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
> line 34, in inner
> response = get_response(request)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
> line 115, in _get_response
> response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
> line 113, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py",
> line 21, in _wrapped_view
> return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/lucas/dev/autocusto/processos/views.py", line 101, in cadastro
> return render(request, 'processos/cadastro.html', contexto)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py",
> line 19, in render
> content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)   File
> "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py",
> line 62, in render_to_string
> return template.render(context, request)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py",
> line 61, in render
> return self.template.render(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 171, in render
> return self._render(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 163, in _render
> return self.nodelist.render(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 936, in render
> bit = node.render_annotated(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 903, in render_annotated
> return self.render(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py",
> line 150, in render
> return compiled_parent._render(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 163, in _render
> return self.nodelist.render(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 936, in render
> bit = node.render_annotated(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 903, in render_annotated
> return self.render(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py",
> line 62, in render
> result = block.nodelist.render(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 936, in render
> bit = node.render_annotated(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 903, in render_annotated
> return self.render(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 986, in render
> output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 670, in resolve
> obj = self.var.resolve(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 795, in resolve
> value = self._resolve_lookup(context)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
> line 836, in _resolve_lookup
> current = getattr(current, bit)   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py",
> line 175, in errors
> self.full_clean()   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py",
> line 376, in full_clean
> self._clean_fields()   File "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py",
> line 388, in _clean_fields
> value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))   File
> "/home/lucas/dev/.virtualenvs/autocusto/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py",
> line 258, in value_from_datadict
> return data.get(name) AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'

I've tried the following solutions with no success:
[Django: how to pass parameters to forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29974105/django-how-to-pass-parameters-to-forms),
[Django Forms: pass parameter to form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660037/django-forms-pass-parameter-to-form)

Don't know what I'm missing!

Comment: I've found the source of the error: 
else:
    formulario = NovoProcesso(escolhas) -----> not able to pass any arguments!

Answer (score 0):

Probably, in NovoProcesso form class or somewhere else you have "," at the end of one of the attribute definition which causes this error. Try to find it out.

You haven't posted whole code but I guess you have something like this:

```py
class NovoProcesso(forms.Form):
   clinicas = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=[]), <- this comma causes an error
```

EDIT: Incorrectly passed arguments to the **init** method as described here [object has no attribute 'get'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667845/object-has-no-attribute-get)